# Creating a power supply for a small machine

Tags: power-supply, 555

I bought a small automatic pipetting machine, but the machine does not have a way to regulate how much liquid is emitted. I would like to modify the power supply that I bought with the machine to be a timed power source that could be adjusted between several time settings until an optimal time is found for my pipetting purposes. The device that has this feature pre-built in cost ten times the version that I bought. The power supply needs to be 12V DC 1A, but otherwise, I do not know how to construct the timing part. I'm thinking a 555 chip, but I really do not know.

Specific question: How do I create a power supply that supplies 12V DC 1A for a varying amount of time on a breadboard?

Comment: There are a few parts I'm not clear about, but this *seems* to be an easy project. (a) Does the existing power supply, produce 12V at up to 1A, and you are looking at switching *that* supply to some kind of pump within the pipetting machine? (b) Roughly what sort of duration do you need e.g. a few seconds, or <1 s, or several hours? (c) To help readers judge how to reply, what sort of electronics experience do you have e.g. have you used a breadboard before? (d) Have you any soldering experience & equipment? (e) Have you measured the supply voltage, to confirm it is a *stable* 12V?

Comment: Wow, this is a actually good question. Congratulations on formatting and writing a clear specific question.

Comment: I think you might have a slightly better chance of good metering if you set your sights on capturing whatever actuator turns the motor on, like the right button.

Comment: Usually pipetting is a precision business. For that reason, I believe you will also need precise control of time. So I would steer clear of the 555 and other analog timers. I would stick with a digital timing source. It could be something like a CPLD, but realistically, I think you should just use a micro-controller of some sort.

Comment: My other comment is that I am very suspicious of the whole idea of using timing to control the volume transferred. I would think you would want some type of positive displacement motion to really control volume accurately. But I have no experience in this area. Just my suspicion.

Comment: If you don't even know how to design a one shot power switch for a fluid valve, how are you going to calibrate? it will vary with temperatures and pressures with non-linear orifice friction coefficients? The electrical  part is trivial. Have you considered an ink jet ceramic pump? or a flow meter?

Answer (score 1):

I'll list the basic design approach I would use:

- Using [TI NE555 timer](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf) as an example (other manufacturers make them too), it can operate from 4.5 V to 16 V power supply. Whether your existing power supply is suitable depends on whether it is regulated or not (since the power supply voltage for NE555 should not exceed 16 V, and *must* not exceed 18 V).
- Configure NE555 as monostable, triggered by manual push switch.
- Decoupling capacitor *required* close to NE555.
- 12 V relay, with contacts rated at minimum of 2 A inductive load (assuming your pump uses maximum of 1 A and allowing for 50% derating). This is used to switch the existing 12 V power supply to the existing pipette pump, for the duration timed by the NE555.
- Low-power relay coils can be driven directly by NE555 output e.g. when sinking <50 mA, NE555 output voltage drop is <1 V. Therefore a 12 V relay with a minimum "pick up" coil voltage of <11 V should work.
- Relay coil freewheeling diode is *required*.
- Choose NE555 timing components to fit desired duration of power to pipette pump.
- Most general purpose relays will need wires soldering to them, in order to connect them to a breadboard. Those wires must not be too thin, to avoid excess voltage drop across the wires, and should be no longer than required. If you can't solder, then ready-made relays-on-PCBs-for-breadboard-use are available, but cost more and limit your choices.

If you need an extra regulated 12 V power supply (it's not clear to me from your question whether that is needed or not), then that would need to be added.

Comment: Depending on how short the timing pulses are, jitter in the mechanical relay timings may be a significant source of error.  It might be better (and probably cheaper) to use a switching transistor instead.  You would also need a switch to select between multiple resistors.